# What does FIN_WAIT1 mean?

Tags: linux, netstat

When I send a HTTPS request from Windows7/Vista to Linux Red Hat 4 the `netstat -an <my_ip>` command shows `FIN_WAIT1` OR `SYNC_RECV` status.

Why do these statuses appear instead of `ESTABLISHED`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The TCP connection is closing, see http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/Course/Section4/11.htm

Comment: Thanks, actually The request comes with support for TLS which is not supported by our server. You post directs in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

What does FIN_WAIT1 mean?: **The TCP connection is closing**

I have a Python example to show the flow:

1. I put my server to listen for connections:

```
>>> import sys, socket
>>> sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> sock.bind(('172.31.35.6', 6677))
>>> sock.listen()
>>> conn, client_address = sock.accept()
```

2. I connect the client to the server

```
>>> import sys, socket
>>> conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> conn.connect(('3.19.54.89', 6677))
```

3. Connection is ESTABLISHED

```
root@ip-172-31-35-6:/home/ubuntu# netstat | grep 6677
tcp        0      0 ip-172-31-35-6.us-:6677 cpea84e3ff37803-c:54944 ESTABLISHED
```

4. Log the netstat status while closing the connection:

```
root@ip-172-31-35-6:/home/ubuntu# while true; do netstat | grep 6677; done > ~/tmp
```

5. Close the connection

```
>>> conn.close()
```

6. Look at the netstat log created in step 4:

```
tcp        0      0 ip-172-31-35-6.us-:6677 cpea84e3ff37803-c:55037 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 ip-172-31-35-6.us-:6677 cpea84e3ff37803-c:55037 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      1 ip-172-31-35-6.us-:6677 cpea84e3ff37803-c:55037 FIN_WAIT1  
tcp        0      1 ip-172-31-35-6.us-:6677 cpea84e3ff37803-c:55037 FIN_WAIT1  
tcp        0      1 ip-172-31-35-6.us-:6677 cpea84e3ff37803-c:55037 FIN_WAIT1  
tcp        0      1 ip-172-31-35-6.us-:6677 cpea84e3ff37803-c:55037 FIN_WAIT1  
tcp        0      1 ip-172-31-35-6.us-:6677 cpea84e3ff37803-c:55037 FIN_WAIT1  
tcp        0      1 ip-172-31-35-6.us-:6677 cpea84e3ff37803-c:55037 FIN_WAIT1  
tcp        0      1 ip-172-31-35-6.us-:6677 cpea84e3ff37803-c:55037 FIN_WAIT1  
tcp        0      1 ip-172-31-35-6.us-:6677 cpea84e3ff37803-c:55037 FIN_WAIT1  
tcp        0      1 ip-172-31-35-6.us-:6677 cpea84e3ff37803-c:55037 FIN_WAIT1  
tcp        0      1 ip-172-31-35-6.us-:6677 cpea84e3ff37803-c:55037 FIN_WAIT1  
tcp        0      0 ip-172-31-35-6.us-:6677 cpea84e3ff37803-c:55037 FIN_WAIT2
```